# sql server 24/7 insert delete select performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am building an C# application that inserts 2000 records every second using Bulkinsert.

Database version is 2008 R2

The application calls a SP that deletes the records when they are more than 2 hours old in chunks using TOP (10000). This is performed after each insert.

The enduser selects records to view in a diagram using dateranges and a selection of 2 to 10 parameterids.

Since the application will run 24/7 with no downtime i am concerned about performance issues.

Partitioning is not an option since the customer dont have an Enterprise edition.

- Is the clustered index definition good?
- Is it neccesary to implement any index recreation / reindexation to increase performance due to the fact that rows are inserted in one end of the table and removed in the other end?
- What about update statistics, is it still an issue in 2008 R2?
- I use OPTION (RECOMPILE) to avoid using outdated queryplans in the select, is that a good approach?
- Are there any tablehints that can speed up the SELECT?
- Any suggestions around locking strategies?

In addition to the scenario above i have 3 more tables that works in the same way with different timeframes. One inserts every 20 seconds and deletes rows older than 1 week, another inserts every minute and deletes rows older than six weeks and the last inserts every 5 minutes and deletes rows older than 3 years.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BufferShort](
    [DateTime] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [ParameterId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BufferStateId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [real] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BufferShort] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DateTime] ASC,
    [ParameterId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteFromBufferShort]
@DateTime DateTime,
@BufferSizeInHours int

AS
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (10000) 
    FROM BufferShort
    FROM BufferStates 
    WHERE BufferShort.BufferStateId = BufferStates.BufferStateId 
    AND BufferShort.[DateTime] < @DateTime
    AND (BufferStates.BufferStateType = 'A' OR BufferStates.Deleted = 'True')

    RETURN 0
END


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectFromBufferShortWithParameterList]
@DateTimeFrom Datetime2(2),
@DateTimeTo Datetime2(2),
@ParameterList varchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Split ParameterList into a temporary table
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM dbo.splitString(@ParameterList, ',');

SELECT *
FROM BufferShort Datapoints
JOIN Parameters P ON P.ParameterId = Datapoints.ParameterId
JOIN #TempTable TT ON TT.Token = P.ElementReference
WHERE Datapoints.[DateTime] BETWEEN @DateTimeFrom AND @DateTimeTo
ORDER BY [DateTime]
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

RETURN 0
END
```

Comment: This fits better to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Btw, if someone also votes to close with that reason it wil be migrated automatically. So instead of upvoting my comment, vote to close.

Comment: This is a developer issue - not an install/maintenance/system issue. It should remain here.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits: [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is not for install issues only, actually it is also for "advanced queries including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and **query-performance**". This question is far too broad for SO and asks for optimizations and best practises. It cannot be answered easily and is not a software algorithm or specific programming problem.

Comment: This question can probably be placed at either site.

Comment: 2000 rows records sounds high for SQL Server, let alone SQL Server Standard Edition. I am not sure your query will benefit from the RECOMPILE option because I suspect the execution plan will always remain the same. To minimize blocking the quick/dirty way would be to use NOLOCK on your SELECTs. Changing the isolation level to Snapshot would be a better approach but would require testing as it could potentially break other queries. Another question what recovery model do you need? Is full absolutely needed? Clustered index looks good IMO.

Comment: Sorry 2000 rows is not that much especially if it does not have too many indexes and is memory resident (not Hekamon) just enough memory to keep it in memory at all times and the clustered index key is an ever increasing one - so there are no page splits on inserts. Please don't use nolock unless you understand the negative implications of nolock.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case of penny wise/pound foolish. You are inserting 150 million records per day and you are not using Enterprise.

The main reason not to use a clustered index is because the machine cannot keep up the quantity of rows being inserted. Otherwise you should always use a clustered index. The decision of whether to use a clustered index is usually argued between those who believe that every table should have a clustered index and those who believe that perhaps one or two percent of tables should not have a clustered index. (I don't have time to engage in a 'religious' type debate about this- just research the web.) I always go with a clustered index unless the inserts on a table are failing.

I would not use the STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE clause. I would only turn it off if inserts are failing. Please see Kimberly Tripp's (an MVP and a real SQL Server expert) article at http://sqlmag.com/blog/statisticsnorecompute-when-would-anyone-want-use-it.

I would also not use  OPTION (RECOMPILE) unless you see queries are not using the right indexes (or join types) in the actual query plan. If your query is executed many times per minute/second this can have an unnecessary impact on the performance of your machine.

Comment: What features of Enterprise Edition would help here?  EE may provide other benefits but I don't see anything in the stated question that warrants it.  The table will only have about 15M rows and will easily be memory resident.

Comment: The reason I would suggest the user consider Enterprise is that partitioning is only one feature that would potentially alleviate the users issues. Partitioning is typically a logical operation and inserting and/or dropping a partition is very fast (meta data is the only thing being updated). I will have to think as to what other Enterprise features could be of use in this situation but every instinct tells me that MS has omitted other features in standard that are of use in this situation. This is a user that is pushing SQL Server in a very robust way and will find other uses of Enterprise.

Comment: It is true that a partition switch, split or merge (for the delete) can be a fast meta-data operation, but it will require a schema-modification lock during the process, which will require exclusive access to the table.  No bulk inserts selects, or deletes may be in occur during the operation.  I think the traditional delete approach would provide better concurrency here.

Comment: I hate to argue with you Dan, (I have read many great articles by you) but the user seems to be doing inserts and deletes in a very controlled way. If there were random inserts/deletes you would be correct.

Comment: Although controlled, I got the impression processing is pretty much continuous so there wouldn't be an opportunity for the schema modification lock without changes.  The might be some wiggle room in the 24x7 availability requirement that wasn't stated, though.

Answer (score 1):

The clustered index definition seems good as long as all queries specify at least the leading DateTime column.  The index will also maximize insert speed, assuming the times are incremental, as well as reduce fragmentation.  You shouldn't need to reorg/reorganize often.

If you have only the clustered index on this table, I wouldn't expect you need to update stats frequently because there isn't another data access path.  If you have other indexes and complex queries, verify the index is branded ascending with the query below.  You may need to update stats frequently if it is not branded ascending and you have complex queries:

```
DBCC TRACEON(2388);
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('dbo.BufferShort', 'PK_BufferShort');
DBCC TRACEOFF(2388);
```

For the @ParameterList, consider a table-valued-parameter instead.  Specify a primary key of Token on the table type.

I would suggest you introduce the RECOMPILE hint only if needed; I suspect you will get a stable plan with a clustered index seek without it.

If you have blocking problems, consider altering the database to specify the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option so that row versioning instead of blocking is used for read consistency.  Note that this will add 14 bytes of row overhead and use tempdb more heavily, but the concurrency benefits might outweigh the costs.